# How to update specific item in LazyColumn without refreshing the list

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to update the specific item in the list but the whole list got updated and refresh. It seem that the Flow emitting new value instead of updating it reason why the list is refresh.

Can any one help me I try different approach but I can't figure out why the whole list is refreshing.

Here is my code in viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ChatViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val messageInteractor: MessageInteractor,
    ) {
    
    private val headerText: String = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle["headerText"])
    private val remoteId: String = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle["remoteId"])
    private val isGroup: Boolean = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle["isGroup"])


    val chatMessageItems: Flow<List<MessageAttachmentState>> =
        messageInteractor.getMessagesInConversationUseCase(remoteId, getMcRequestType())
            .map { messageAttachments ->
                messageAttachments.map {
                }
                mapToMessageAttachmentStates(messageAttachments)
            }
            
}
```

Here is my composable function

```
@Composable
fun ChatScreen(
    chatViewModel: ChatViewModel
) {

 val chatMessageItems = chatViewModel.chatMessageItems.collectAsState(emptyList())


   LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalGradientBackground()
                .padding(bottom = 70.dp),
            reverseLayout = true,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {

            items(
                items = chatMessageItems.value,
                key = {
                    it.id
                }
            ) { chatItemState ->

                ChatItem(
                    chatItemState = chatItemState,
                    chatItemSeparator = { date, topSpace ->
                        ChatItemsSeparator(date, topSpace)
                    }
                ) { item ->


                    when (item.type) {
                        MessageType.TEXT -> {
                            TextMessage(
                                text = item.msgText.toString(),
                                isIncoming = item.isIncoming,
                                messagesState = item.messageState,
                                dispositionState = item.disposition,
                                senderName = item.senderName,
                                time = item.timestamp.toString()
                            )
                        }

                        MessageType.IMAGE -> {
                            ImageMessage(
                                isIncoming = item.isIncoming,
                                messagesState = item.messageState,
                                dispositionState = item.disposition,
                                senderName = item.senderName,
                                time = item.timestamp.toString()
                            ) {
                                AsyncImage(
                                    model = item.imageData,
                                    contentDescription = "Message image",
                                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                        ViewUtils.viewImage(item.imageData, context, null)
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        MessageType.FILE -> {
                            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                                FileMessage(
                                    fileName = item.fileName.toString(),
                                    fileSize = item.size.toString(),
                                    isIncoming = item.isIncoming,
                                    messagesState = item.messageState,
                                    dispositionState = item.disposition,
                                    senderName = item.senderName,
                                    time = item.timestamp.toString(),
                                    icon = if (item.isIncoming) R.drawable.ic_message_file_receive else R.drawable.ic_message_file_send
                                )
                                if (item.messageState == MessagesState.SENDING)
                                    ProgressIndicator(item.isIncoming)
                            }
                        }

                        MessageType.VIDEO -> {
                            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                                FileMessage(
                                    fileName = item.fileName.toString(),
                                    fileSize = item.size.toString(),
                                    isIncoming = item.isIncoming,
                                    messagesState = item.messageState,
                                    dispositionState = item.disposition,
                                    senderName = item.senderName,
                                    time = item.timestamp.toString(),
                                    icon = if (item.isIncoming) R.drawable.ic_message_video_receive else R.drawable.ic_message_video_send
                                )
                                if (item.messageState == MessagesState.SENDING)
                                    ProgressIndicator(item.isIncoming)
                            }
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Note: I tried to collect the changes from the Room Db. For instance the state of the message. Then when the Ui collect the changes it will recompose. This change trigger by external call back meaning it is not trigger by the event from the UI.

Comment: Compose UI is a declarative UI system. There is no difference between "update the specific item in the list" and "the whole list got updated". You tell Compose "this is what the list should contain now", and Compose handles it from there.

Comment: Thank @CommonsWare. Yes, you are right. I now figure out and fix the problem. I use rememberUpdatedState in the composable so it can remember its state and only recompose when the value changes.